image padding affects my image with grayscale background
I am working on a Python code to make a group of images (white background with black content) of equal size by adding white pixels (padding). But when running the code, a gray background appears as shown.


script:
import os
from PIL import Image

def add_padding(image_path, target_size):

try:
    # Open the image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    
    # Get current size
    width, height = image.size
    
    # Calculate padding
    left_pad = (target_size[0] - width) // 2
    top_pad = (target_size[1] - height) // 2
    right_pad = target_size[0] - width - left_pad
    bottom_pad = target_size[1] - height - top_pad
    
    # Add padding
    padded_image = Image.new("L", target_size, color="white")  
    padded_image.paste(image, (left_pad, top_pad))
    
    return padded_image

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error processing image '{image_path}': {e}")
    return None

tried for binarization: i use several types
`
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/44_5_6.png',0 )

adaptive_threshold_mean = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 6)
adaptive_threshold_gaussian = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 6)

plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
titles = ["Adaptive Threshold - Mean", "Adaptive Threshold - Gaussian"]
for idx, thres in enumerate([adaptive_threshold_mean, adaptive_threshold_gaussian]):
    plt.subplot(1,2,idx+1)
    plt.imshow(thres, 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[idx])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])`

the results:

I also tried with different threshold
 img = cv2.imread('/content/44_5_6.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_2 = cv2.imread('/content/44_5_6.png')
_, global_threshold_40 = cv2.threshold(img_2, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, )
_, global_threshold_94 = cv2.threshold(img_2, 94, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, )
_, global_threshold_120 = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, )

the results:

Can anyone please tell me the issue here and how I can solved?

stop thresholding. do not do that. your source is a picture with alpha channel.
